# HTML Material Design Button

Tags: html, css, button, material-design

I want to create a website for an organisation's GCSE options and I'm currently drafting it using Notepad++. I am partially a novice at this.

I want to create a hoverable dropdown, where it lists all the options and if clicked on, it opens up a card all about the subject. I like the Material Design concept and here's part of the code:

```css
/* Style The Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Compulsary</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">English Language</a>
    <a href="#">English Literature</a>
    <a href="#">Mathematics</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, I also want to link each subject to this kind of card:
https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section

I made a sample card:

```css
.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 512px;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 176px;
  background: url('https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/maths_blackboard.jpg') center / cover;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__menu {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Mathematics</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    This is one of the compulsary subjects and is crucial. It involves geometry, algebra, data, and numbers.
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Done
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I link the card to one of the dropdown options, so it opens up and how do I also link the 'Done' button on the card to close the card?

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By linking the card, I believe you meant to say you want the cards to popup when the links are clicked. This can be achieved easily using javascript/jquery. A pure "hacky" css solution is also possible but NOT recommended.

The following solution uses jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function() {
    $(".background-mask").show();
    $(".demo-card-wide.mdl-card").show();

    $(".mdl-card__supporting-text").text(
      $(this).attr("data-content")
    );

    $(".demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title").css('background', 'url(' + $(this).attr("data-img") + ') center / cover')
  });

  $(".mdl-button").click(function() {
    $(".demo-card-wide.mdl-card").hide();
    $(".background-mask").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
/* Style The Dropdown Button */

body {
  position: relative;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 512px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 176px;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__menu {
  color: #fff;
}

.background-mask {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Compulsary</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" data-content="English Language Content" data-img="https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/maths_blackboard.jpg">English Language</a>
    <a href="#" data-content="English Literature Content" data-img="https://images7.content-hcs.com/commimg/myhotcourses/blog/post/myhc_24232.jpg">English Literature</a>
    <a href="#" data-content="Mathematics Content" data-img="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/english-language-day.jpg">Mathematics</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="background-mask"></div>

<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Mathematics</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    This is one of the compulsary subjects and is crucial. It involves geometry, algebra, data, and numbers.
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Done
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Use data-attributes to add relevant content to the links that can be inserted in the cards. In this case, I have added the following:

```
<a href="#" data-content="English Language Content" data-img="https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/maths_blackboard.jpg">English Language</a>
<a href="#" data-content="English Literature Content" data-img="https://images7.content-hcs.com/commimg/myhotcourses/blog/post/myhc_24232.jpg">English Literature</a>
<a href="#" data-content="Mathematics Content" data-img="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/english-language-day.jpg">Mathematics</a>
```

Comment: That's great, however, is there a way to open the card in the middle of the page, dimming everything else and ONLY making the card clickable?

Comment: Sorry, you must've misunderstood me, sorry, but I meant it opens in the very middle of the WHOLE page, and  so that you can ONLY click on 'DONE'. Also, could you link English Language to a copy of the card, but with random text, so I can tell how to link the card SEPARATELY to each button?
Thanks

Comment: My bad, I forgot to save my edits the last time. I have updated again, with the new requirements. Hope this solves everything.

Comment: Thanks! It looks good from stackexchange, but here's the most important question. How do I add that to my code? It may sound stupid (sorry) but should the main code be like this:

https://pastebin.com/AZEUcF7h

with the button.js being:

https://pastebin.com/q19BgJqp


Please can you add separate a separate HTML code and a js if required and send the link using pastebin?

Thank You

Comment: Have you never linked external files to your html before? It's actually pretty simple. The stylesheet and JS files contents will be same as the snippet. Only thing you need to do is add the files in the html `head`.
Index page: https://pastebin.com/1qFTcxe2, Stylesheet: https://pastebin.com/x3KN0ByG. JS: https://pastebin.com/jZDtNCLH

Comment: Yes. I marked and upvoted it, but FINAL question.

For Mathematics, I want https://www.tes.com/sites/default/files/maths_blackboard.jpg

For English Literature, I want https://images7.content-hcs.com/commimg/myhotcourses/blog/post/myhc_24232.jpg

And for English Language, I want https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750w/english-language-day.jpg

How can I have separate wallpapers on the cards?

Comment: Again, use data attributes. I have updated the answer.